# Add number to association query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following associations:

```
image1
image2
image3
```

I need to do the following:

```
User.first.image1
```

...but, I need to build `image1` based on the **`params[:id] = 1`**

I tried something like: `User.first "image#{1}".to_sym,` but this failed

I also tried `User.first."image#{1}"`

Comment: `User.first.send("image#{1}")`

Comment: @Sontya, can you please provide an answer below. This is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send method is the equivalent of calling the given method on the object. So if the `image1` variable has a value of "some_name", then `User.first.send("image#{1}")` is the same as `User.first.image1`

Try this

```
User.first.send("image#{1}")
```